# add new actionlink extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, extension-methods

From what I can see, there are various extension methods for HtmlHelper. There is a class called LinkExtensions that holds various extension methods related to links. I want to add an additional ActionLink extension that has a different number of parameters (so another overriden method called ActionLink). How do I go about doing this?

So far I have done this, and it does not work (doesn't appear as an extension method):

```
public static class ActionLinkExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString ActionLink(this HtmlHelper helper, String linkText, int someNumber, String actionName, String controllerName, Object routeValues, Object htmlAttributes)
    {
        return helper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName, routeValues, htmlAttributes);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure to include the namespace in which your extension method is defined.
E.g:

```
using Whatever.Namespace.You.Used;
```

Comment: That was it, needed Import Namespace in the view.